# Chain together Pandas functions like in R

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying make my code more concise by chaining together pandas functions in one line. This is easy to do in R, but not in Pandas. How would I go about doing this?

R

```
data$dist = trimws(gsub('F','', data$dist))
```

Python

```
data['dist'] = data['dist'].str.replace('F','')
data['dist'] = data['dist'].str.strip()
```

Comment: You can just extend your call: `data['dist'] = data['dist'].str.replace('F','').str.strip()`

Comment: Starting with Pandas 16.2, you can utilize [pipe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for R like chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) what is very nice for chaining:

```
data = data.assign(dist = data['dist'].str.replace('F','').str.strip())
```

Another possible solution is as mentioned in comment [AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081218/chain-together-pandas-functions-like-in-r/44081980#comment75185984_44081218):

```
data['dist'] = data['dist'].str.replace('F','').str.strip()
```

Also you can check tutorial from [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas) - [method chaining](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html).